# Deserialize an inner array to objects using JSON.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

An existing JSON-based web-service returns a fairly messy JSON object, where all the useful data is contained in the elements of an array which is itself the content of a 1-element array. Something like this (I'm anonymising it, hopefully no typos):

```
{"rows":[[
    {"name":"John","time":"2016-03-20 01:00:00","id":"2","code":"1234"},
    {"name":"Sam","time":"2016-03-20 01:00:00","id":"24","code":"999"},
    {"name":"Paul","time":"2016-03-20 01:00:00","id":"12","code":"6512"}
]]}
```

Using JSON.net I need to access each of those row sub-elements but I'm not sure how to iterate over this and if I should be deserializing to a concrete type or just reading the raw data from my json object.

The data will be aggregated inside a method so the 'type' of each `row` is not something that needs to be known outside the method.

`rows` will *always* be a 1-element array containing an array of elements as shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Fals's solution should work well, but if you want to do away with the `RootObject`, you can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) to parse the JSON and get the data into a simple list of items that is easy to work with.

Assuming you have a class defined for the item data like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this to get your list of items:

```
List<Item> items = JObject.Parse(json)["rows"][0]
                          .Select(jt => jt.ToObject<Item>())
                          .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FtB3Cu

---

If you want to avoid declaring any classes at all and instead use an anonymous type, you can change the code to this:

```
var items = JObject.Parse(json)["rows"][0]
                   .Select(jt => new 
                   {
                       name = (string)jt["name"],
                       time = (DateTime)jt["time"],
                       id = (string)jt["id"],
                       code = (string)jt["code"]
                   })
                   .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QXUzZ

Comment: Thanks Brian. Is there any way you can further combine this with a method-local anonymous type to avoid declaring a concrete type? Or does one simply have a private inner class?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Yes, you can use anonymous types.  I've edited my answer to show how.  It should also work with an inner class if you choose to go that route.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, your root object contains a `List<List<>>`:

Your object should look like:

```
public class InnerObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<InnerObject>> rows { get; set; }
}
```

Then use JSON.NET:

```
string json = @"{'rows':[[
                    {'name':'John','time':'2016-03-20 01:00:00','id':'2','code':'1234'},
                    {'name':'Sam','time':'2016-03-20 01:00:00','id':'24','code':'999'},
                    {'name':'Paul','time':'2016-03-20 01:00:00','id':'12','code':'6512'}
                ]]}";

var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

By the way, this site [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) can generate the C# class from JSON, makes the life ease :)

EDIT:

You can also use dynamic, and then avoid the parser from the `RootObject:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
rootObject.rows[0] <--- should have what you need
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a neat way to avoid needing `RootObject` without having to manually hack the string? e..g just get an array/List of `InnerObject` back from a JSON.net call?

Comment: @Mr.Boy You can create a custom JsonCreationConverter, http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm

Comment: @Mr.Boy see the edit above, makes thinks more dynamic :)